# Redirect to another url after post request (AJAX, EXPRESS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

As a part of learning node.js servers I'm working on a little log-in website. There's a site you can open and enter your username which will then be sent through an ajax post request to the server and saved into an array of all users. I wanna make it so that after you submit your username, you will be redirected to another page, unique for every username, where you will be able to see the information about you username. Sort of a 'manage your account' site.

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to redirect me to this page after I have submitted an username.

Say for example you submit a username 'kokot' and it's the 3rd username that's been submitted so far. Thus, in the 'players' array, your user object will look something like this `{id: 2, username: 'kokot'}`.
Now I want to redirect you to the url [localhost:2000/players/2](https://localhost:2000/players/2) to see the info about your specific username.

NODE JS

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

let players = [];

//loads the home page
server.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});

//loads the page with the list of players
server.get('/players', (req, res) =>{
    res.send(players);
});

server.get('/player/:id', (req, res) =>{
    res.send(players[req.params.id]);
});

//takes a new username and saves it to players array
server.post('/', (req, res) =>{
    console.log('NEW PLAYER: ' + req.body.username);

    players.push({
        id: players.length,
        username: req.body.username
    });
});








/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
server.listen(2000, () => console.log('LISTENING ON PORT 2000'));
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>PISKVOREC</h1>

    <form id="userForm">
        username
        <input type="text" name="text" id="userFormInput">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="userFormSubmit">
    </form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(()=>{

        let homeUrl = 'http://localhost:2000';

        let $userForm = $('#userForm');
        let $userFormSubmit = $('#userFormSubmit');


        //submits a new username to the server
        $userFormSubmit.click(() =>{
            $.post(homeUrl, {
                username: $('#userFormInput').val()
            }, function(){
                console.log('USERNAME SUBMITTED TO SERVER');
            });

            $.
        });
////////////////////
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for you responses and ideas

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Sure, see below:

```
server.post('/', (req, res) =>{
    console.log('NEW PLAYER: ' + req.body.username);

    players.push({
        id: players.length,
        username: req.body.username
    });

    res.redirect(`/player/${req.body.username}`);
});
```

**UPDATE**
Demo with vanilla Express.js app

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

app.post('/this', (req, res, next) => {
  res.redirect(`/that/${req.body.username}`);
});

app.get('/that/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(req.params);
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.hbs

```
<form method="post" action="/this">
    <input id="username" name="username" value="vader" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

results in a redirect to: `http://localhost:3000/that/vader`

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work...I added the line you wrote but after submitting it stays on the [http://localhost:2000/?text=username&Submit=Submit](http://localhost:2000/?text=username&Submit=Submit) page

Comment: Hmm, I just justed tested above and works fine. There must be something else in your code that is causing a problem. The url you sharing seems odd and not sure how that is being generated: http://localhost:2000/?text=username&Submit=Submit is the server.post('/' route even being hit?

Comment: however, the $.post AJAX seems like it fires the post request (otherwise it wouldn't save the username into the players array - which it does) but doesn't seem to execute the callback function which orders it to output 'USERNAME SUBMITTED TO SERVER' in the console since there's never any output into the console whatsoever...idk how that is possible

Comment: And yeah the server.post rout is hit for sure since it always prints 'NEW USER' into the cmd...I guess the url you mentioned is some sort of default form url that is generated idk

Comment: Updated the answer with a proof of concept. The redirect works as designed. Please check your own code using breakpoints. Cheers